# Floating point exception(core dumped) error ,in my c code

Tags: c, binary, operators

I am trying to work with binary numbers AND logical operator without using `&`. When I entered the example 1111 and 1000, a floating point exception (core dumped) occurred. I am waiting this code same length two binary numbers and after print for example print:1001 and 1111 = 1001

```
  #include<stdio.h>
int length(int a,int b);
int andop(int a,int b);
int main(){
    int first,sec;
    do{
        printf("First integer:  ");
        scanf("%d",&first);
        printf("\nSecond integer:  ");
        scanf("%d",&sec);} 
    while(andop(first,sec)==0); 
    printf("\n%d AND %d= %d",first,sec,andop(first,sec));
    return 0;
}

int andop(int a,int b){

   int a_1,b_1;
   int result=0;

    a_1=a;
    b_1=b;
    while(a_1>1){/*Checking if first is binary or not,the loop briefly checks if the number in each digits either 1 or 0,and if it dont returns 0 it also quit the loop and stop asking for new numbers*/
        if (a_1%10>1){
             printf("\nInteger should be binary,please enter 2 new integers\n");
             return 0; 
         }
     a_1=a_1/10; 
    }   
    while(b_1>1){/*Checking if first is binary ,the loop briefly checks if the number in each digits either 1 or 0,and if it dont returns 0 it also quit the loop and stop asking for new numbers*/
        if (b_1%10>1){
            printf("\nInteger should be binary,please enter 2 new integers\n");
            return 0;
      }
      b_1=b_1/10; 
    }

    while (length(a,b)>0){ 

    result=result+(a%10)*(b%10);  
    a=a/10;
    b=b/10;
    if(length(a,b) == 0){
    break;
    }
    result=result*10;
    }
    return result;
    }

 int length(int a,int b){
   if(a == 0 || b == 0){
    return 0;
   }
   int temp_a,temp_b;
   int length_a=0,length_b=0;

   temp_a=a;/*i assign the number into the temporary variable _a and _b*/ 
   temp_b=b;
   while(temp_a>0){//checking how many digit a is
        temp_a=temp_a/10;
        length_a++;
   }
   while(temp_b>0){//checking how many digit b is
        temp_b=temp_b/10;
        length_b++;
   }

   if(length_!=length_b){/* If they don't have same digits ,print an error message and continue to taking number from user*/
         printf("\nInteger should have same length,please enter 2 new integers\n");
         return 0;
     }   

   return length_a;

}
```

Comment: The error is "divide by zero", right? So check your divisions.

Comment: Where exactly ı am doing this?

Comment: Look at all your `/` operators. If the divisor is a constant (other than 0), it's not a problem. That should reduce the possibilities rapidly. And use a debugger.

Comment: `while(length_a/length_b!=1) {...}` loop is bad. Use `if(length_a  != length_b) { ..}`

Comment: Yeah i did some edit and i am still taking same error.,it probably should be in the int andop(int ,int ) but i cannot find what the  problem is?

Answer (score 2):

The following code is the source of the problem:

```c
   while(length_a/length_b!=1){/* If they don't have same digits ,print an error message and continue to taking number from user*/
         printf("\nInteger should have same length,please enter 2 new integers\n");
         return 0;
     }
```

You are using a very strange way to test if two variables (`length_a` and `length_b`) are the same! Further, if `length_b` is zero (as it appears to be, at some stage), then the division will cause the error.

You can just use a simple comparison of the two variables:

```c
    if (length_a != length_b) {/* If they don't have same digits ,print an error message and continue to taking number from user*/
        printf("\nInteger should have same length,please enter 2 new integers\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

*EDIT: There are a number of other errors in your code but the suggestion I have given will address the specific error you have asked about.*

Comment: I changed my code with your advice and ı am still taking same error .Problem should be in different section

Comment: @jamesMoriarty  Did you leave your original code in, as well as using that which I suggested? Otherwise, I can't really see how you could possibly get the *same* error, as there is nowhere else in your code where you divide by (or take a modulo of) a zero value.

Answer (score 1):

In your program, the floating point exception occurs because of division by zero in function length. 
You should check if a or b is 0 before doing anything in length().
Try adding this at the start of length

```
if(a == 0 || b == 0)
    return 0;
```

Also, check if length() returns 0 before multiplying result by 10 in andop
i.e. change `length(a, b)` to

```
if(length(a, b) == 0)
    break;
```

Even after this, your program will print the result in reverse order, so you will have to print the result in reverse order. Try creating a function for that.

Comment: also, taking these variables as int will create a problem if result is something like, `10000` or `00010`, it will just print `1` or `10`. Because printing `int` by printf wont print any starting 0s. Try using strings for this.

Comment: I editted my code at above,and using string is not allowed sir,and ı am still taking same error,ı think in this code , ı am trying divide by 0 any number which ı used,and if ı handle with this error can ı do reversing without string?Probably looks possible